# How to make a list?

Tags: xna, shader, hlsl

I know this question sounds stupid but, what's the syntax to make a list in HLSL ?
I found how to make an array (Type name[x]) but not how to make a list. :/

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can.  You can make an array and keep track of a count in another variable though.

```
float3 points[12]; 
int pointCount;
```

Then in XNA you can set the array and then the count:

```
List<Vector3> vectors = new List<Vector3>();
vectors.Add(new Vector3(12, -13, 14));
effect.Parameters["points"].SetValue(vectors.ToArray());
effect.Parameters["pointCount"].SetValue(vectors.Count);
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use ListOf<> to make a list. Hope it will helps you.

Comment: Well it helps a little bit but this doesn't tell me how to use it.  Like this ?:  ListOf<Type> myList;  myList.Add(Type) ?

Comment: As far as I can tell "ListOf" is not part of HLSL.

Answer (score -3):

Here's the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) on Lists in .NET.

Usage:

```
List<Type> listVariable = new List<Type>();
```

Example:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
```

Additionally, you can use a [Hashtable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) if you want to refer to the items in the list by a (unique) string.

```
Hashtable myHash = new Hashtable();

// Add item.
myHash.Add("item1", new HLSLShader());

// Remove item.
myHash.Remove("item1");
```

Comment: the List class does not exist in HLSL